# What are the requirements of doing 2k@60hz for 2 monitors over a single usb c hub (usb to hdmi)

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

What are the requirements of doing 2k@60hz for 2 monitors over a single usb c hub converted to hdmi? What stats do I need to be looking for?

I have a usb hub with 2 hdmi ports. It is advertised to do 4k@60hz for 1 monitor or 4k@30hz for 2 monitors. I have attached 2 monitors and am attempting to do 2560x1440@60z, but it maxes out at 1920x1080.

I'm not trying to get help troubleshooting this particular hub, but generally, what specs should I be looking for in a usb c hub/adapter in order to achieve this?

Simple math would show

```
2x4k@30hz is 3840*2160*30*2 = 497664000 
2x2k@60hz is 2560*1440*60*2 = 442368000
442368000 <= 497664000
```

but clearly I'm not understanding something since it isn't displaying at that resolution.

Comment: Regrettably, some ads are created by marketing staff who might not be cognizant of product capability (and some might just be lying). Consider buying from a reputable vendor that would let you return the hub. This seems to be a growing concern for USB, where old products are sold that don't quite meet newer requirements.